# When a linear combination of full-rank matricies is of full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a nonzero vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and I have $n$ full-rank matrices $A_i\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$, where $i$ runs from $1$ to $n$ and $n \le m$. I construct $n$ vectors $y_i=A_ix$ and combine them as a $n \times n$ matrix $$F=\begin{bmatrix}y_1 & y_2 & \cdots & y_n\end{bmatrix}.$$
The question is when $F$ is nonsinglar.

If $F$ is singular then the columns are linearly dependent and there exist $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\ldots$, $\lambda_n$ not all zero simultaneously such that $$\lambda_1 y_1 + \lambda_2 y_2 + \ldots + \lambda_n y_n=0,$$ that is $$\left(\lambda_1 A_1 + \lambda_2 A_2 + \ldots + \lambda_n A_n\right)x=0.$$

So the question is what are the requirements for the full-rank matrices $A_i$ such that any linear combination of these matrices is also full-rank?
If it is simpler, then we can consider the case $n=m$, i.e. $A_i$ is square nonsingular.

Comment: One need not imply the other, assuming $x$ is fixed of course. More precisely, we need $x\not\in \ker(\sum \lambda_i A_i)$ whenever the $\lambda_i$ are not all $0$.

Comment: Actually, I need it for all $x$, $|x|=1$.